# which class I should use for Activity result callback array?

Tags: android, android-studio, onactivityresult, registerforactivityresult

I am trying to use the new `ActivityResultLauncher` Intent for activity result, when I make the second parameter callback (`ActivityResultCallback`) Android Studio asks me which Class I want to import for the result and gives me 3 options.

[image]

I don´t know which one I need to use and which one is for the "old" method (`startActivityForResult`).

I tried the 3 ways and they all seems to pass, but I get different errors in the Logcat for every option.

What is the correct choice?

This is the code:

```java
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // There are no request codes
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    doSomeOperations();
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: check all 3 ... with wrong - it will not compile :D ... or check documentation of `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult`

Comment: It seems that it compiles in all 3 ways XD

Comment: *errors in the Logcat* ? not popssible .. it should not compile at all as we have `abstract @NonNull ActivityResultLauncher<I> <I, O> registerForActivityResult(
    @NonNull ActivityResultContract<I, O> contract,
    @NonNull ActivityResultCallback<O> callback
)`  so you cannot put different `O` into `ActivityResultCallback<O>` and `ActivityResultContract<I, O>` ... anyway it should be the one from androidx

Comment: I think the errors in the logcat are not directly related, I will try using `androidx.activity.result`

Answer (score 0):

It should be `androidx.activity.result`

Sample code (*in Kotlin*):

```
val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { 
        result: androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult ->
            when (result.resultCode) {
                Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                    // Your code
                }
                Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                    // Your code
                }
            }
        }
```